# How can I reference an existing VPC Endpoint in AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

How can I lookup and reference an existing VPC Endpoint in my Stack so that I can pass it to API Gateway RestApi() for private API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

msshenke's answer returns Ivpc what I needed was vpc endpoint reference.

This is what I found

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint.html#static-from-wbr-interface-wbr-vpc-wbr-endpoint-wbr-attributesscope-id-attrs

Need to supply the existing vpce id and the security group.

### CDK v1

```
const ivpc = Vpc.InterfaceVpcEndpoint.fromInterfaceVpcEndpointAttributes(this, "VPC", {
    port: 443,
    vpcEndpointId: "vpce-1234567890",
    securityGroups: ["https-sg"] // or whatever you are using
});
```

### CDK v2

> *`securityGroups` property optional*

```
const ivpc  = ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint.fromInterfaceVpcEndpointAttributes(this, `vpceLookup`, {
  vpcEndpointId : `vpce-abcdefgh123456789`,
  port          : 443
});
```

Answer (score -2):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.Vpc.html#static-from-wbr-vpc-wbr-attributesscope-id-attrs

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.VpcAttributes.html

You'd need to have the vpc id and availability zones your subnets are using at a minimum.

```
const vpc = Vpc.fromVpcAttributes(this, "VPC", {
    vpcId: "vpc-1234567890",
    availabilityZones: ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b"] // or whatever you are using
});
```