# How can I lookup an existing VPC Endpoint Service in CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

I know there is a way to [lookup an existing VPC or VPC Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64346701/how-can-i-reference-an-existing-vpc-endpoint-in-aws-cdk)

But, is there a way to look up a [VPC Endpoint Service in CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.VpcEndpointService.html)?

I need to find out the availability zones of an existing VPC Endpoint Service.

Comment: Using CDK only, or anyother way?

Comment: In what context? Cdk or application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do it, so I had to rely on AwsCustomResources to

```js
    import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2'
    import * as custom_resources from 'aws-cdk-lib/custom-resources'

    // Custom resource is needed to call the AWS DescribeVpcEndpointServices API in order to retrieve the
    // public availability zones associated with the VPC Endpoint
    //
    // "Sometimes a single API call can fill the gap in the CloudFormation coverage. In this case you can use the AwsCustomResource construct. 
    // This construct creates a custom resource that can be customized to make specific API calls for the CREATE, UPDATE and DELETE events. 
    // Additionally, data returned by the API call can be extracted and used in other constructs/resources (creating a real CloudFormation 
    // dependency using Fn::GetAtt under the hood)."
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources-readme.html#custom-resources-for-aws-apis
    const vpcEndpointAvailabilityZonesApi: custom_resources.AwsCustomResource = new custom_resources.AwsCustomResource(
      this,
      "DescribeVpcEndpointServices",
      {
        onCreate: {
          service: "EC2",
          action: "describeVpcEndpointServices",
          parameters: {
            ServiceNames: ["com.amazonaws.vpce.us-east-1.vpce-svc-yourIDhere"]
          },
          physicalResourceId: custom_resources.PhysicalResourceId.of(Date.now().toString()),
        },
        onUpdate: {
          service: "EC2",
          action: "describeVpcEndpointServices",
          parameters: {
            ServiceNames: ["com.amazonaws.vpce.us-east-1.vpce-svc-yourIDhere"]
          },
          physicalResourceId: custom_resources.PhysicalResourceId.of(Date.now().toString()),
        },
        policy: {
          statements: [
            new iam.PolicyStatement({
              actions: ["ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointServices"],
              resources: ["*"],
            }),
          ],
        },
        functionName: "DescribeVpcEndpointServices"
      }
    );

    // "By default, a VPC will spread over at most 3 Availability Zones available to it."
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2-readme.html#control-over-availability-zones
    const vpcEndpointServiceAZs :string[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      vpcEndpointServiceAZs.push(vpcEndpointAvailabilityZonesApi.getResponseField(`ServiceDetails.0.AvailabilityZones.${i}`))    
    }
```

I couldn't lookup an existing Endpoint Service, so I had to create two AwsCustomResource calls, put one in each stack, and then create resources there.

I ended up having to split my CDK into two stacks, one with the VPC and one passing the VPC object to a secondary dependent stack. Note, this is the VPC object reference (`ec2.Vpc`), not the VPC ID. Using `fromLookup` will not work, since the ID is not determined until deploy-time, not build time.

As for the `DescribeVpcEndpointServices` call, you had to fix the number of AZs, since it is not possible to pre-determine the number from a variable. For most VPCs though, it's going to be three by default.